# How to capitalize first letters in each word of RichTextBox.Text?

Tags: c#

How can I switch the first letter of each word of `RichTextBox.Text` to upper case?

For example, I need to switch this text:

```
"This is a big and beautiful dog."
```

To this text:

```
"This is a Big And Beautiful Dog".
```

That means I need to capitalize the first letter in the words which include three letters or more. It is difficult for me. Also, there are many lines in `RichTextBox.Text`.

Comment: Here is a similar discussion but not the same http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b7ea95d7-f27b-4933-9f80-467e84e879cd/

Comment: Since this is homework, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
string[] str = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
string a="";
string b="";
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str.GetValue(i).ToString().Length > 2)
    {
        b = str.GetValue(i).ToString().Replace(str.GetValue(i).ToString().Substring(0, 1),   str.GetValue(i).ToString().Substring(0, 1).ToUpper());
    }
    else
    {
        b = str.GetValue(i).ToString();
    }
    a = a + " " + b;              
}
richTextBox1.Text = a;
```

Comment: Endless concatenation is issue here

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```cs
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = 
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
richTextBox1.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(RichTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: The output is not same as user922907 wants.  " This Is A Big And Beautiful Dog. "

Comment: Your right but at this point, he will have to parse each components to check if the length of the sentence part and if > 2 do the job.

It can be done through a String.Split

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize the first letter of each word according to `CultureInfo` by simply using this:

Note: "test" is a sample property as Name, Surname, Address, etc.

```cs
text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? 
    string.Empty : 
    CultureInfo
        .CurrentCulture
        .TextInfo
        .ToTitleCase(text.ToLower(new CultureInfo("tr-TR", false)));

Please note that, in here there is an extra control for null values.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this extension. Note - it makes everything Capitalized, so that `eMail` will become `Email`. Good about it - it works on arrays with no concatenations.

```cs
public static string Capitalize(this string value)
{
    char[] chars = value.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    bool isNewWord = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i]))
        {
            isNewWord = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (isNewWord)
        {
            chars[i] = char.Parse(chars[i].ToString().ToUpper());
            isNewWord = false;
        }

    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```